# I don't understand unitary of ${e^{iAt}}$ from HHL algorithm

Tags: programming, qiskit, quantum-gate, hhl-algorithm

I tried to implement the following circuit in the image below but with the red circled gates replaced with a unitary controlled ${e^{iAt/2}}$ and controlled ${e^{iAt/4}}$
[image] The image came from this paper [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S037596012030462X) and someone already implemented this circuit [here](https://github.com/dreamingangela/ibmq_hhl/blob/master/hhl.qasm).

The matrix A is :
[image]
And t = 2π 
For ${e^{iAt/2}}$ I found that the matrix is equal to an X gate which is same as the paper.
[image]

For ${e^{iAt/4}}$ I got this matrix. 
[image]
But in the paper they use U3(-pi/2,-pi/2,pi/2) as target bit and U1(3π/4) afterwards at control bit.
The unitary matrix from both qubit is something like this.(I use qiskit to find the unitary matrix)
[image]

While my ${e^{iAt/4}}$ connected with a control bit gives different unitary matrix.
[image]
Am I missing something or is there anything wrong with my ${e^{iAt/4}}$ unitary?

Answer (score 3):

The mistakes comes from the fact that you missed the controlled-part of the U3 gate.

So your equivalent gate should really be:

```
qr = QuantumRegister(2, 'qubit')
qc = QuantumCircuit(qr, ClassicalRegister(2, name='classicabit'))
qc.cu3(-math.pi/2, -math.pi/2, math.pi/2, 0, 1)
qc.u1(3.0*math.pi/4,0)
```

The unitary result of :
[image]

is :

```
[[ 1. +0.j   0. +0.j   0. +0.j   0. +0.j ]  
 [ 0. +0.j  -0.5+0.5j  0. +0.j  -0.5-0.5j]  
 [ 0. +0.j   0. +0.j   1. +0.j   0. +0.j ]  
 [ 0. +0.j  -0.5-0.5j  0. +0.j  -0.5+0.5j]]
```

Where you find your unitary matrix :

> [[ -0.5+0.5j  -0.5-0.5j]
> [ -0.5-0.5j  -0.5+0.5j]]

controlled by qubit 1.

I did not understand how you implemented your ${e^{iAt/4}}$ controlled gate, at least the methods you use do not work with my qiskit version so you can check with this code :

```
A = np.array([[1.5, 0.5],[0.5, 1.5]])
qc = QuantumCircuit(2)
gate=ex.UnitaryGate(expm(A*1.j*math.pi/2)).control(1)
qc.append(gate, [0,1])

qasm_sim = BasicAer.get_backend('unitary_simulator')
result = execute(qc, qasm_sim).result()
print(result.get_unitary())
```

[image]

which produces

> [[ 1. -5.55111512e-17j  0. +0.00000000e+00j  0. +0.00000000e+00j 0.+0.00000000e+00j]
> [ 0. +0.00000000e+00j -0.5+5.00000000e-01j  0. +0.00000000e+00j   -0.5-5.00000000e-01j]    [ 0. +0.00000000e+00j  0. +0.00000000e+00j  1. -7.21644966e-16j
> 0. +0.00000000e+00j]    [ 0. +0.00000000e+00j -0.5-5.00000000e-01j  0. +0.00000000e+00j   -0.5+5.00000000e-01j]]